# Vulkan Fitting with EGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es, egl, vulkan

There seems to be lot of buzz regarding Vulkan the new graphics API - https://www.khronos.org/vulkan

My question is related to - How well existing EGL interface will accommodate the Vulkan API ?, With Vulkan new stateless approach, Will EGL have to be replaced with Vulkan based alternative ?

The three APIs that have been, until now, accessible from EGL (OpenGL, OpenGL ES and OpenVG), work with per-thread contexts , how about Vulkan ?

Comment: My money is on an extension that will interact with the windowing system. That's the way Mantle was specified.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Specifically this will likely require two extensions. One on the EGL side and one on the Vulkan side (`WsiEGL` anyone?).

Comment: Multithreaded context has been set as a key point in the drafts of vulkan...

Comment: Probably it might follow any of the two                                                    a) New EGL api can be exposed that binds a draw and a read surface to a context (an EGLContext) is added.                            
b) Or applicable Vulkan methods take a context (an EGLContext pointer) as one of their arguments.

Answer (score 7):

EGL is explicitly thread-safe.

<strike>This means that through an extension of Vulkan you could bind a `EGLSurface` as a rendertarget in a pipeline or use it as a parameter for a bufferswap. This `EGLSurface` would be created through the normal way and the `eglQueryString(display, EGL_CLIENT_APIS)` of the creating `EGLDisplay` must then include "Vulkan".</strike>

The context bit is trickier though. I expect that there will be a dummy (zero state) context used to mark the thread as using Vulkan to render.

EGL will not even come into the picture. You get the instance from scratch using the loader. And there is a set of extensions that will take a window handle from the OS and provide a vkSwapchain with several vkImage that you can render to and send to the monitor.

Answer (score 4):

No EGL with Vulkan. New stuff will be there [Vulkan Window System Integration](http://ahcox.com/vulkan/wsi/vulkan-window-system-integration-talk-at-siggraph-2015/)